# migrate mysql to mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to ask which is the best way to write a code php (because I want to run it through bash(linux) ) to convert data from mysql database to mongodb database.
I do not need code, I just ask

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to migrate from mysql to mongodb.

In most cases you need to plan re-design you data storage.

MongoDB has no foreign keys. It is NoSQL. You can't simply convert DB from MYSQL to MongoDB.

If you realize it, and when all actions and thoughts are ready, you will need to write migration patch. Yes, possibly in PHP. Then run it in bash. And you are done.